# How to sort special letters (typescript)?

Tags: javascript, sorting, typescript, special-characters

I want to sort some letters in ts... sort method and localCompare() sort in this way Ä, Å, Ö, instead of Å, Ä, Ö. How to sort any letters corectly?

I have a list of objects:

```
class MyObj { id:number,
name: string,
type:number
}

I tried var list: MyObj[] = a list of objects

list.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.name.toUpperCase().localeCompare(b.name.toUpperCase());
        });
```

**UPDATE**

Yes, georg answer was correct: I found this too:

```
var strings = ["Ålex", "Ålex3", "Älex2"];
var sorter = new Intl.Collator("sv", { usage: "sort" });

strings.sort(sorter.compare);
```

same result.

Thanks a lot!

**VERY IMPORTANT**

Don't use localCompare because it's very worse at execution time.

Use Intl.Collator!

```
var browserLanguage = function () {
        const defaultLanguage = "en";
        const browserLanguage = this.window.navigator.language ||
            (this.window as any).navigator.browserLanguage;

        const currentLanguage = browserLanguage.split('-')[0];

        if (supportedLanguages.indexOf(currentLanguage) < 0) {
            return defaultLanguage;

        } else {
            return currentLanguage;
        }
}

const intlCollator = new Intl.Collator(browserLanguage, { usage: "sort" });

    list.sort(function (a, b) {
                return intlCollator.compare(a.toUpperCase(), b.toUpperCase());
            });
```

Comment: It prints correctly `["Ä", "Å", "Ö"].sort( ( a, b ) => a.localeCompare(b) )`

Comment: that code prints "Ä", "Å", "Ö" not "Å", "Ä", "Ö"

Comment: On chrome it prints `"Å", "Ä", "Ö"` correctly

Comment: I saw now... hmmm

Comment: On which browser are you able to replicate your issue?

Comment: ["Älex2", "Ålex", "Ålex3"].sort( ( a, b ) => a.localeCompare(b) ) try this ;)

Comment: it won't work, the result is: ["Ålex", "Älex2", "Ålex3"]

Comment: In Danish the sort order is Æ, Ø, Å - where in the world is the sort order Ä, Å, Ö, or  Å, Ä, Ö ???

Comment: In Swedish: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_alphabet

Comment: Wow. I speak Swedish, Never knew :O

Comment: http://forums.htmlhelp.com/lofiversion/index.php/t762.html

Comment: my client wants that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localeCompare` obviously depends on the locale, and different locales use different rules ("collations") to compare extended characters. For example, in English, `A`s with different diacritics are all the same, while Swedish treats them differently:

```js
console.log(["Älex2", "Ålex0", "Ålex3", "Alex1"].sort(( a, b ) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en')));

console.log(["Älex2", "Ålex0", "Ålex3", "Alex1"].sort(( a, b ) => a.localeCompare(b, 'sv')));
```