# Sorting array keys case insensitive with swedish chars

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I'm trying to sort an array by keys with swedish chars in an alphabetical  "Natural sort order". This is the test array:

```
var test = [];
test["abc"] = [];
test["ABC"] = [];
test["test"] = [];
test["Test"] = [];
test["åäö"] = [];
test["ÅÄÖ"] = [];
```

The desired result is the order the array is created (abc, ABC, test, Test, åäö, ÅÄÖ), but I can't figure out how to get that order.

I've tried using:

```
var sortedKeys = Object.keys(test).sort();
```

And:

```
var sortedKeys= Object.keys(test).sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
});
```

But I can't get the desired order of the keys. Here's a jsfiddle with some tests:
https://jsfiddle.net/3cs491gq/

Thanks for any help sorting (!) this out.

Comment: Why are you adding string keys to an array? It looks like you need an associative array (i.e. dictionary-like behaviour). As such `Object` is the right choice here. The reason this works is that an array is an object. You're not using anything array-like here. IMO `test` should be `var test = {};`

Comment: You’re creating an object, and as such key order is not guaranteed.  Using an array, element order is guaranteed.

Comment: @spender the real code is a bit more complex than this and I tried to make a simple example here.

Comment: Without a definition of  **'a "natural" way'** you'll have answers shooting into the dark.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear but I'm thinking in an "Natural sort order" a la: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order ... I've updated the question a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `toLowerCase`, and just use `sort` with `localeCompare`:

```js
var test = [];
test["ÅÄÖ"] = [];
test["abc"] = [];
test["ABC"] = [];
test["test"] = [];
test["Test"] = [];
test["åäö"] = [];

var sortedKeys = Object.keys(test).sort((a, b) => !/[a-z]/i.test(a) ? 1 : (/[a-z]/i.test(b) ? 0 : -1));

console.log(sortedKeys);
```

Comment: Hahaha did you not see that i posted the same answer before you :)

Comment: No - look at your output and OP's desired output, they're different.

Comment: Yes the result of your code is also wrong the desire result is `abc, ABC, test, Test, åäö, ÅÄÖ` you should compare `a to b` instead.

Comment: Fixed @Alen.Toma - my code outputs the correct order.

Comment: Now why would you use regexp when you simple have to write `a.localeCompare(b);`. well anyway good job.

Comment: @JackBashford thanks for the help. It sure works but I didn't work in my actual code. There's a jsfiddle here with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ygn9bfzq/ The order there becomes `["Stockholm", "Ö Test", "t test", "ÅÄÖ Test"]` whereas I want it to be `["Stockholm", "t test", "Ö Test", "ÅÄÖ Test"]`

Comment: It seems like this way of sorting works well: `var sortedKeys = Object.keys(listData).sort(new Intl.Collator("sv", { usage: "sort" }).compare);` ... at least in Chrome and Safari. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583099/how-to-sort-special-letters-typescript

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the proper parameters to [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Parameters) like so:

```js
var test = [];
test["ÅÄÖ"] = [];
test["abc"] = [];
test["ABC"] = [];
test["test"] = [];
test["Test"] = [];
test["åäö"] = [];

var r = Object.keys(test).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, "sv", {sensitivity: 'case'}));

console.log(r);
```

In this case we add `sv` for the `Swedish` locale and `sensitivity: 'case'` as the option.

Answer (score 1):

Well your code seems to work. You should not use `toLowerCase` though.

Here i made a test for you.

```js
var test = [];
test["ÅÄÖ"] = [];
test["abc"] = [];
test["ABC"] = [];
test["test"] = [];
test["Test"] = [];
test["åäö"] = [];


var data =Object.keys(test).sort(function(a,b){
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I get this order when I run this test: `["åäö", "ÅÄÖ", "abc", "ABC", "test", "Test"]` and not the desired `["abc", "ABC", "test", "Test","åäö", "ÅÄÖ"]`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way that seems to work quite well, at least in new versions of Chrome, Safari and Opera. This question was very helpful:
[How to sort special letters (typescript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583099/how-to-sort-special-letters-typescript)

```
var test = [];
test["abc"] = [];
test["ABC"] = [];
test["test"] = [];
test["Test"] = [];
test["åäö"] = [];
test["ÅÄÖ"] = [];

var sortedKeys = Object.keys(test).sort(new Intl.Collator("sv", { usage: "sort" }).compare);

console.log(sortedKeys);
```

There's a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ryv4hjk5/